# Question about solvable finite dimensional Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite dimensional solvable Lie algebra. Given that we can take subspaces $\mathfrak{a}_{i}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathfrak{a}_{i}/\mathfrak{a}_{i+1})=1$ and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{a}_{0}\supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{1} \supseteq \cdots \supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{n}=0$, why is it that for all $i$ there is some $j$ such that $\mathfrak{g}^{j}\supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{i} \supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{i+1} \supseteq \mathfrak{g}^{j+1}$? Here $\mathfrak{g}^{j} = [\mathfrak{g}^{j-1},\mathfrak{g}^{j-1}]$ and $\mathfrak{g}^{0} = \mathfrak{g}$. For instance, if $\mathfrak{g}$ is $n$-dimensional, and $\mathfrak{a}_{1}=\mathrm{span}\{v_{1},v_{2},\dots,v_{n-1} \}$, I don not see clearly why $\mathfrak{g}^{1}\subseteq \mathfrak{a}_{1}$. I would appreciate your help in making this a bit clear. Also I have not found results on the dimension of the ideals $\mathfrak{g}^{j}$.

I am following the proof of the following result in *Lie groups: beyond an introduction*.

> An $n$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is solvable if and only if there exists a sequence of subalgebras
> $$
> \mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{a}_{0}\supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{1} \supseteq \cdots \supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{n}=0
> $$
> such that, for each $i$, $\mathfrak{a}_{i+1}$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{a}_{i}$ and $\mathrm{dim}(\mathfrak{a}_{i}/\mathfrak{a}_{i+1})=1$

Comment: I think you are switching the order of choosing the $\mathfrak{g}^j$ and $\mathfrak{a}_i$. I think it is not true in general that you can take any sequence $\mathfrak{a}_i$ you want and then get the property in your question. It is true that once we know the $\mathfrak{g}^j$ we can choose matching $\mathfrak{a}_i$ so that the property holds. I explained that latter point in answer to another question (hence with a bit different notation) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4799048/101420

Comment: O wait... I see now the claim says 'if and only if', so there must be some version where the $\mathfrak{a}_i$ come first. However it is not stated that they do have the property you describe, maybe they give rise to some other $\mathfrak{b}_i$ that do. I will think a bit more about it...

Comment: @Vincent the proof starts as follows: form the commutator series $\mathfrak{g}^{j}$ and interpolate subspaces $\mathfrak{a}_{i}$ in the sequence so that $\mathrm{dim}(\mathfrak{a}_{i}/\mathfrak{a}_{i+1})=1$. After that, it says that one has the inclusion that I mentioned: $\mathfrak{g}^{j}\supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{i} \supseteq \mathfrak{a}_{i+1} \supseteq \mathfrak{g}^{j+1}$.

Comment: @Vincent From the answer you had given in the link I can see how it is obtained. Thank you very much!